# Read inbox messages from facebook graph API v2.9

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I was facing a problem in accessing the inbox messages from facebook graph api.
With v2.3 of the api, it was quite easy, we just needed to give a call at this "me/inbox?fields=id,from,message" node and we get the list of all the messages.
The only permission needed here was "read_mailbox"
But with v2.9, there is no permission named "read_mailbox". So my question is how can I get the same result with v2.9
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: there is no way to get access to the user mailbox anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @luschn already said, it is not available anymore.

The endpoint was removed with Graph API 2.4 (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4). For Pages it is still possible to access the conversations/mailbox.